# uncheck Bootstrap checkbox buttons - Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a data filtration function in my app, where users can use checkboxes and dropdowns to select how they want to filter the data.

I am using the bootstrap checkboxes:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-primary active">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
 </label>
</div>
```

I have a **clear filter** buttons which clears all the users inputs from the filters, resets all checkboxes, all drop downs, all text fields.

I was able to reset drop downs like this:

```
// sectorPicker is drop down
document.getElementById('sectorPicker').reset();
```

Below is the image of my checkboxes:

[image]

But I can't figure our how to reset the Bootstrap checkboxes on the screen to uncheck all checkboxes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this will remove the checked property and also active class from its parent label

```
$(":checkbox").prop('checked', false).parent().removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, It will loop through all selected checkboxes and make them un checked. Or you can give each checkbox a class attr and then make loop over it.

```
     $( "input:checked" ).each(function(){
           $(this).removeAttr("checked");
           $(this).parent().removeClass("btn btn-primary");
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
           $(this).parent().addClass("btn btn-default");
     });
```

//Way two:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-primary active">
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychk" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychk" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" class="mychk" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
 </label>
</div>

$(".mychk").each(function(){
 $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this but my checkboxes still remain highlighted. If you check my question I've posted an image. You can see they are highlighted as Blue even after clearing them.

Comment: That is your button class, you need to remove btn btn-primary class from label element, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know bootstrap checkboxes use properties instead of attributes.

`$("[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false)` something like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#You_id_checkbox').removeAttr("checked");
```